# Why is my matlab plot not evolving using finite difference method?

Tags: matlab, plot, pde

I am trying to use a finite difference method to solve the heat equation for a given function u0. I want to evolve it in time using plots to see each frame change but when I run it all I see is the same frame over and over. I am aware of the error at the ends due to me not giving "u" a first or last index which will cause more overall error in the solution. I am not very good at matlab so I am not sure if I am writing my nested piece correctly.

```
% set up domain in time and space 
 t_step = .1;
 tspan = [0 :t_step:1000];
 L = 10; %length of domain
 n = 64; 
 dx = 2*pi/(n-1); %spacing
 x = 0:dx:2*pi; 
 x = x'; %make x vertical vector


% initial conditions for the function
u0 = sin(2*pi*x/L)+0*cos(3*2*pi*x/L) + 0.2*(cos(5*2*pi*x/L))+0*randn(size(x));

plot(x,u0);title('initial condition');pause;

t = 0;

for m = 1:tspan(end)
     u = u0;
     t = t + t_step;

         for j= 2:n-1
               u(j,m) = u0(j-1) - 2*u0(j) + u0(j+1)/dx^2; %u(1) and n left out

          end

     plot(x,u(:,m))
     pause(0.01);

end
```

Comment: Your finite difference equation is incorrectly entered, you need some brackets.

Comment: Where would I need to place them?

Comment: Try writing down what your code says and you should be able to work it out.

Comment: Also you're resetting `u` to `u0` every time step, hence the solution is not evolving.

Comment: @Steve Yep, found that fix a couple weeks ago. Thanks for feedback.